# Eclipse:my android application gets crashed at starting

Tags: java, android, eclipse

below is my java file.I m trying to run it on emulator in eclipse.when i run this app it shows the error shown in image below.

```
package com.example.library;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText ed_user,ed_pwd;
Button btn_login;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ed_user=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ed_pwd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(ed_user.getText().toString().equals("admin") &&         ed_pwd.getText().toString().equals("admin"))
            {
                Intent i=new   Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"LOGIN       Unsuccessful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

[this is the error i receive,shown in image][1]
[image shows the details of my avd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9b6j.jpg)

Comment: didn,t get you.what do you want?@jas

Comment: are you aware about logcat ?

Comment: i have done.is that it?

Comment: Show us your [logcat](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/files/2011/11/android_logcat_filtering_main.png)

Answer (score 5):

It seems that `btn_login` is null,
Find it inside `onCreate()`

So define it as

```
 btn_login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
```

before     `btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`

Note : replace `R.id.btn_login` with button id defined in xml file.

Comment: now the same error comes after the button is clicked.